# Matlab: How to re-using the corresponding amplitude without re-compute the signal?

Tags: c++, matlab, signals

Guys,

I need your help!

Matlab : Plot this continuous-time signal on Matlab.

[image]

1. Define and plot the following continuous-time signals. and choose a a time interval that is relevant for this signal.

2.For signal x(t) in above, define y(t) =1+2x(-2t+3) by reusing the corresponding amplitude vetor defined in question #1 and defining an appropriate time vector. Plot x(t) and y(t) on the same plot.. Note that you are not allowed to recompute the signal, you have to use your knowledge about shifting, scaling, etc. (Hint: fliplr() or flipud()).

The question #2 really stop me to contine, how can I get the y(t) =1+2x(-2t+3) witout recompute the signal? And I knew how to use the re-compute the signal to let it work, but it require me not to re-compute the signal. Below is my code:

```
 figure;
 t = -5:0.01:5;
 y = exp(-t).* heaviside(t) + (exp(-t) .* (exp((2*t)-4)-1) .* heaviside(t-2)) - (exp(t-4) .* heaviside(t-4));

 t2 = (-2*t) + 3;
 y2 = exp(-t2).* heaviside(t2) + (exp(-t2) .* (exp((2*t2)-4)-1) .* heaviside(t2-2)) - (exp(t2-4) .* heaviside(t2-4));
 y3 = 1 + (2*y2);

    plot(t,y,'g');
    hold on;
    plot(t,y3,'r')
```

And I tried to use to coding without re-compute the signal with below code:

```
figure;
clear all
t = -5:0.01:5;
y = exp(-t).* heaviside(t) + (exp(-t) .* (exp((2*t)-4)-1) .* heaviside(t-2)) - (exp(t-4) .* heaviside(t-4));
    plot(t,y,'g');
    hold on;

t2 = -t.* 2 + 3;
y2 =  1 + 2 * y;

    plot(t2,y2,'r');
```

The graph without re-compute the signal will increase size by 2, and move left by 3 which is not same as above. so, I recognized it's wrong for my code. also, it stated let we need to use  fliplr() or flipud(), but I don't know where to use this function.

Please give me a help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot((t+3)/2,1+2*fliplr(y),'k')
```

The `1+2*y` you already had. You need the `fliplr` to do the `x(-t)` instead of `x(t)`. Then you need to inverse the relation on t: `x(2t)` will "move" twice faster than `x(t)` so if you plot the same data it has to be plotted on a twice smaller interval, hence the `/2`.